# Create literal without repeating in typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I create a readonly object with a literal type without repeating the value.

Working example with *'myLiteralValue'* explicitly typed:

```
const createSettings = () => ({ appType: 'myLiteralValue' as 'myLiteralValue' });

switch (createSettings().appType) {
  case 'myLiteralValue':
    break;
}
```

The type gets widened to *string* if I don't explicitly type it and that would make the switch  if I removed the repeated 'myLiteralValue'

```
const createSettings = () => ({ appType: 'myLiteralValue' });

switch (createSettings().appType) {
  case 'myLiteralValue':
    break;
}
```

While breaking out the *appType* into a const still repeats but in a different way:

```
const myLiteralValue = 'myLiteralValue';
const createSettings = () => ({ appType: myLiteralValue });

switch (createSettings().appType) {
  case 'myLiteralValue':
    break;
}
```

Comment: Break how? What do you mean?

Comment: Does [this part of the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) help? I am not sure what you mean by "repeating". You can always use a `const` and than use the typeof to get the literal type.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I updated the examples with clarifications

Comment: @SebastianSebald Kind of, but I would still need to create a interface for the type and that would make me repeat the literal string 'myLiteralValue' in the interface

Comment: What is your real code like? Obviously, the `appType` can have more values, and so the literal also has multiple values instead of just one as in your example. Also, your code is fine in playground even when `appType` is a string, so what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readonly` modifier to declare constant properties (in this case, a literal property).

```
class Settings {
    constructor(public id: any) { }
    readonly appType: "myLiteralValue";
}

const createSettings = (id: any) => new Settings(id);
```